# Python list of tuples: organize by unique elements to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples, say:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1),('b',2),('c',1),('a',2),('d',3)]
```

I need to get correspoding values for any (unique) second element in a tuple. For example as a dictionary. 
Output:

```
dict = {1:['a','c'],2:['b','a'],3:['d']}
```

Whats the most pythonic way of doing it? Help much appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably go with a `defaultdict` like jamylak, but if you want a "real" dictionary, you can use [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('a', 1),('b',2),('c',1),('a',2),('d',3)]
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in list_of_tuples:
...     d.setdefault(item[1],[]).append(item[0])
...
>>> d
{1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'a'], 3: ['d']}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list_of_tuples = [('a', 1),('b',2),('c',1),('a',2),('d',3)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for c,num in list_of_tuples:
        d[num].append(c)


>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b', 'a'], 3: ['d']})
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is mainly useful when the default is expensive to construct; this isn't the case with an empty list - probably better to just use a normal dict and do `d.setdefault(num, []).append(c)`.

Comment: @Ivc: That may be so, but unless performance really is a relevant issue here, I find defaultdicts easier to understand.